# Override a page table entry with another on a x64 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, ubuntu-14.04, virtual-memory

I have made a kernel module that takes the virtual addresses of two variables, call them **foo** and **bar**, and walks trough the page tables up to their physical addresses.

I would like to modify the page table entry of **foo** so it will be the same as the page table entry of **bar**, thus making it as **foo** and **bar** are in the same page frame. Could you help me achieve this?

Below is the code I wrote to traverse the page tables.

```
pgd_t *pgd;
pud_t *pud;
pmd_t *pmd;
pte_t *ptep, pte;

pgd = pgd_offset(mm, address);
if (pgd_none(*pgd) || pgd_bad(*pgd))
    return -EINVAL;

pud = pud_offset(pgd, address);
if (pud_none(*pud) || pud_bad(*pud))
    return -EINVAL;   

pmd = pmd_offset(pud, address);
if (pmd_none(*pmd) || pmd_bad(*pmd))
    return -EINVAL;

ptep = pte_offset(pmd, address);
if (!ptep)
    return -EINVAL;
pte = *ptep;
```

I am sure I need to flush the TLB and maybe modify some flags in order to achieve what I want, but I lack the required knowledge.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to do more than just change PTEs. Otherwise, on the next task switch, the kernel will just overwrite your PTE changes. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GilHamilton I am trying to trick the Memory Manger into thinking that both __foo__ and __bar__ are in the same physical address page, so when my user space code will access __foo__, it will actually access __bar__.  

As an example, if __foo__ is a function, and __bar__ is a buffer that is 2-3 pages long, I want to make the virtual address of __foo__ point to the physical address of __bar__, and instead of executing the code within __foo__ it will execute the contents of the buffer __bar__.  

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Very difficult to accomplish that in a reliable way. What are you trying to accomplish at a higher level?  (*Why* do you want to trick the memory manager?)

Comment: @GilHamilton At a higher level, I am trying to see if I can make a code injection attack using this method. Basically, I would like my __bar__ buffer to contain __printf("Hello attack\n")__ and I would expect this to be printed after execution, instead of whatever __foo__ does. I want to do this as a proof of concept, so maybe a less reliable way can also work.

Comment: A kernel module runs in supervisor mode and so it can do whatever it wants to the machine or to any process running within it. A "code injection attack" is therefore kind of pointless. (If you really want to do this, yes, it's possible. But it will be very difficult to implement reliably and will require a deep understanding of linux memory management in order to do it without crashing the system.)

Comment: @GilHamilton I am aware that I can do whatever I want since I can gain supervisor access, but this is an exercise for me. By doing what I want, I can change the behavior of a running program. Could you point me to a resource where I could read more about what I am trying to achieve? I want to understand what are the necessary steps that I need to do; ex: traverse the page tables up to ptes, maybe use spinlocks, modify flags, counter etc. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are several books on the design of the linux kernel that are available for download. Start with those. After that, you'll need to look at the source code. As I said before, this requires a deep understanding of linux memory management; there's no cookbook for it because you're deliberately going outside the standard model. There are many pieces that will need to fit together just right in order to do this without crashing the kernel. (It's my guess you'll lose interest in doing it before you learn enough to actually achieve it. Of course it would still be educational so...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing this answer hoping that this will prove useful for someone in the future.

I have managed to modify the page tables for the virtual addresses of two variables **foo** and **bar** so the mm will see them as residing in the same physical page.

The code that does this is below:

```
#include <linux/module.h>                                                                                                                                                                                      
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/thread_info.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <asm/tlbflush.h>
#include <asm/page.h>
#include <asm/pgtable.h>

pgd_t *foo_pgd, *bar_pgd;
pud_t *foo_pud, *bar_pud;
pmd_t *foo_pmd, *bar_pmd;
pte_t *foo_ptep, *bar_ptep, foo_pte, bar_pte;

/* We will step through the page tables until we reach the
 * PTE for both foo and bar */

/* Get PGD */
foo_pgd = pgd_offset(current->mm, foo_address);
if (pgd_none(*foo_pgd) || pgd_bad(*foo_pgd))
    return -EINVAL;

bar_pgd = pgd_offset(current->mm, bar_address);
    if (pgd_none(*bar_pgd) || pgd_bad(*bar_pgd))
        return -EINVAL;

/* Get PUD */
foo_pud = pud_offset(foo_pgd, foo_address);
if (pud_none(*foo_pud) || pud_bad(*foo_pud))
    return -EINVAL;

bar_pud = pud_offset(bar_pgd, bar_address);
if (pud_none(*bar_pud) || pud_bad(*bar_pud))
    return -EINVAL;   

/* Get PMD */
foo_pmd = pmd_offset(foo_pud, foo_address);
if (pmd_none(*foo_pmd) || pmd_bad(*foo_pmd))
    return -EINVAL;

bar_pmd = pmd_offset(bar_pud, bar_address);
if (pmd_none(*bar_pmd) || pmd_bad(*bar_pmd))
    return -EINVAL;

/* Get PTE */
spin_lock(current->mm->page_table_lock);    
foo_ptep = pte_offset_map(foo_pmd, foo_address);
if (!pte_present(*foo_ptep))
    return -EINVAL;

bar_ptep = pte_offset_map(bar_pmd, bar_address);
if (!pte_present(*bar_ptep))
    return -EINVAL;

/* Trick foo into thinking he resides in the same page as bar */
*foo_ptep = *bar_ptep;

spin_unlock(current->mm->page_table_lock);

/* We need to flush the tlb afterwards */
__native_flush_tlb();
```

This may not be as robust as what @GilHamilton had in mind, but this got the job done for me.

I hope this will prove to be useful!

Eduard